# GLib-GIO-Message with Canopy python

Tags: python, glib, canopy

I just installed an activated the Canopy 64 bit in a Linux box running Ubuntu 12.04. In my .bashrc I set the path to be

```
PATH=/home/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:"$PATH"
```

Canopy itself adds the line

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /home/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

Then, when running a python script I get the following error

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

This is solved when I comment the line added by Canopy to my .bashrc.
Anyone understands what's going on here?

Comment: Odd. Not sure it's relevant, but for completeness, where in .bashrc are each of these lines, and are there any PATH-related lines between them?

Comment: The VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT line is last. And yes, there are a number of path related lines between them, appending paths for other applications